# clone select element and selected options are disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

the scenario is when all the selected options are there. so, the option is disabled. but when I clone select options and then disable not show in options.

[image]

*in the above image disabled options.*

[image]
**if I add clone select option button then option aland isands id enable**

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="select_" id="select_cn" tabindex="1">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="United States">United States</option>
        <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
        <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
        <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
      </select>
      
    <div class="apnd"></div>

    <button class="clon">
        BTN
    </button>
    <script>

        $('body').on('click', '.clon', function () {
            $('#select_cn').clone().insertBefore('.apnd')
        })

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".select_").change(function () {
        var value = $(this);
        var prevVal = value.data("prev");
        var otherSelects = $(".select_").not(this);
        otherSelects.find('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').attr('disabled', true);
        if (prevVal) {
            otherSelects.find('option[value="' + prevVal + '"]').attr('disabled', false);
        }
        value.data("prev", value.val());
    });
});
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

aland isands

Comment: It's because you execute your code in document.ready. Anything you do afterwards, like clone, append, delete elements, will not invoke this code again, so your select will not get disabled.

Comment: Pretty sure you asked this earlier (now deleted) - same as before: you're using event delegation for the click event, also use it for the change event.

Comment: @Lalalena   can you pls send the code